# Last User-Agent String is overiding the previous one

Tags: user-agent

I have included this script from Rog.ie (http://archive.is/Zf3Pd)

```
<script>
var b = document.documentElement;
b.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
b.setAttribute('data-platform', navigator.platform );
b.className += ((!!('ontouchstart' in window) || !!('onmsgesturechange' in window))?' touch':'');
</script>
```

and the following data useragents (6,3 is windows 8.1 and 6.1 is windows 7):

```
html[data-useragent*='MSIE'][data-platform='Windows NT 6.3']
.example {
color: black;
}
html[data-useragent*='MSIE'][data-platform='Windows NT 6.1']
.example {
color: white;
}
```

However regardless of whether i'm on windows 8.1 or 7 it is only working for which ever useragent is at the bottom i.e with the above example the color is white, but if is reversed as follows the color is black.

```
html[data-useragent*='MSIE'][data-platform='Windows NT 6.1']
.example {
color: white;
}

html[data-useragent*='MSIE'][data-platform='Windows NT 6.3']
.example {
color: black;
}
```

I am testing these user agents on my laptop browsers developed through dreamweaver so i am not testing on a server yet. Is the data user agent code not working because the site is not yet on a server or am i doing something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What is your browsers user agent string?

Comment: found solution using the following link. it looks outdated but the source file on github includes latest browsers and operating systems.      [link]http://sainfoinc.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/77767-css-browser-selector-clever-technique-to-help-you-on-css-hacks-  [link]http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/     [link]https://github.com/rafaelp/css_browser_selector